# SnowFlake Failed to cast variant value "" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ

Tags: dbt, snowflake-schema

Generating external tables in SnowFlake works very well, but when you use the dbt to do this, it generates errors in the validation of fields that come null for timestamp_ntz.

CREATE OR REPLACE EXTERNAL TABLE EX_USERS
( deleted_at timestamp_ntz as (NULLIF(value :deleted_at, '')::timestamp_ntz)

dbt

- name:    deleted_at data_type: timestamp_ntz description: "deleted_at"

Failed to cast variant value "" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `::timestamp` [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html) could be used:

```
deleted_at timestamp_ntz AS (TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(some_col) )
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get a `Failed to cast` error back from Snowflake, the value returned in the error message is (unfortunately) trimmed of spaces. This means that it might not be `''` that is your `deleted_at` but it could be `' '` or `'  '` etc.

In other words, your `NULLIF` might be comparing one (or more) spaces against the empty string. In Snowflake, this comparison will return false. For example

```
SELECT NULLIF(value :deleted_at, '')::timestamp_ntz
FROM (SELECT {'deleted_at':' '} as value)
```

will return

`SQL Error [100071] [22000]: Failed to cast variant value " " to TIMESTAMP_NTZ`

Now, you could use `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ`, but that would mean silently ignoring any "real" errors (such as attempting to convert say `2023-02-29` to a timestamp. Therfore, it might be preferable to code this

```
NULLIF(TRIM(value:deleted_at), '')::timestamp_ntz
```

or, you could use the `TRIM_SPACE` option on the `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` if you are happy for all input columns to be trimmed